# Exclude value of a record in a group if another is present

Tags: sql, oracle

In the example table below, I'm trying to figure out a way to sum amount over id for all marks where mark 'C' doesn't exist within an id. When mark 'C' does exist in an id, I want the sum of amounts over that id, excluding the amount against mark 'A'. As illustration, my desired output is at the bottom. I've considered using partitions and the EXISTS command, but I'm having trouble conceptualizing the solution. If any of you could take a look and point me in the right direction, it would be greatly appreciated :)

sample table:

```
id   mark  amount
------------------
1    A     1
2    A     3
2    B     2
3    A     2
4    A     1
4    B     3
5    A     1
5    C     3
6    A     2
6    C     2
```

desired output:

```
id   sum(amount)
-----------------
1    1
2    5
3    2
4    4
5    3
6    2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select 
  id, 
  case 
     when count(case mark when 'C' then 1 else null end) = 0 
     then 
        sum(amount)
     else 
        sum(case when mark <> 'A' then amount else 0 end)
  end
from sampletable
group by id
```

Comment: Your second `sum` should probably read: `sum(case when mark <> 'A' then amount else 0 end)` (should be `amount` instead of `1`).

Comment: @AndriyM rush mistake. Fixed it

Comment: @Adrian, thank you for your reply. After implementing your solution I realized I asked the question wrong! This solution does exactly what I asked, but what I asked for is not what I need :). If you have the heart to give this another go, I've asked a new question with my actual requirements at [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13169830/exclude-value-of-a-record-in-a-group-if-another-is-present-v2)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my effort:

```
select id, sum(amount) from table t where not t.id = 'A' group by id 
having id in (select id from table t where mark = 'C') 
union  
select id, sum(amount) from table t where t.id group by id 
having id not in (select id from table t where mark = 'C')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  id,
  sum(amount) AS sum_amount
FROM atable t
WHERE mark <> 'A'
  OR NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM atable
    WHERE id = t.id
      AND mark = 'C'
  )
GROUP BY
  id
;
```